# Prevent popping views when reselecting UITabBar item

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBar` class that extends `UITabBarController` and on it I have 3 `UINavigationController`s with each own rootController. Then on the first one I push additional `UIViewController`. When I change tabs everything works normally, on every view there are things that are suppose to be there.

The problem occurs when I am on tab one and then click on the same tab again. When I do that, from some reason the view that was pushed on it is popped back to rootView.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to prevent this?

I take suggestion either in swift or objective c.

Comment: *"I have a tabbar class that extends UITabbarController"* ... are you doing something in that code that re-inits / re-loads that tab's View Controller? Or, does your View Controller do something that resets its Nav Controller to its root VC?

Comment: Have you implemented any UITabBarControllerDelegate method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this , as the default of tabbar when you select the same tab it displays the root  , so implement this delegate  `UITabBarControllerDelegate`

//

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController , UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       self.delegate = self

    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

        return tabBarController.selectedIndex != tabBarController.viewControllers?.index(of: viewController)  
    }

}
```